# Hook into existing shortcodes to manipulate the attributes?

Tags: shortcode, hooks

I am looking for a way to hook into an existing shortcode.
Lets say there is a shortcode called  [product attr1="whatever1" attr2="whatever2"].

If the shortcode is called in a post, I like to manipulate one of the attributes, lets say attr2 depending on the author of the post.

Is there a way to hook into shortcodes to manipulate them?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Only if the implementation uses filters (which is not required, but good practice). Can you post the shortcode implementation here?

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to post the code, it is a payed plugin (aawp). But there is a function called "render_shortcode" and at the end of the function there is a "return apply_filters( 'aawp_shortcode_content', $str );".

Comment: Have you considered asking their support? The supplied code is only able to change the final HTML output, it doesn't have any information anymore on single attributes.

Comment: I asked about 5 times (via email) and the answers have always referred to something completely different. So not helpful at all. :-/

Comment: Sorry, but third party plugins are generally off topic here. And for more generic answer we'd need at least the part of the plugin code that starts the shortcode method. If it has something like `$attributes = apply_filters('aawp_shortcode_atts', $atts);` then you can filter. If not, probably not.

Comment: OH, I didn't know that (third party plugins). And thanks for your help. Finally I got an answer from a tech there: "I regret to inform you that we do not have any filters that you can use to manipulate the shortcode added to WordPress content". So problem not solved, but at least I know that it is not working :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the filter `do_shortcode_tag` and see if a filter on there pulls in the values you want to look at / tweak / etc.

Docs: [do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/do_shortcode_tag/)

There's also `pre_do_shortcode_tag` for intercepting values before the shortcode generation.

Docs: [pre_do_shortcode_tag](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_do_shortcode_tag/)